# Translating 'Django-Oscar'

Tags: python, django, translation, django-oscar

I want to learn how to build an opensource e-commerce site. For this purpose I'm using 'Django' framework with 'Oscar' extension.

I read the whole tutorial here: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.5/index.html, where there is a `Translation` tutorial. I followed it (must say that it has missing steps). This part says that, in order to translate a page you must create two folders and a symbolic link:

```
mkdir locale i18n
ln -s $PATH_TO_OSCAR i18n/oscar
```

Then, for each language you want to translate:

```
./manage.py makemessages --symlinks --locale=<language code>
```

That's correct but, besides that, you must compile `.po` files in order to get the final traduction in `locale` folder (`.mo` files). After that you must include the traductions into `settings.py` of project (or app). This is done with the following code:

- In terminal (from root directory of project): `$ django-admin.py compilemessages`
- In `settings.py` add:

  LANGUAGES = [
      ('de', _('German')),
      ('en', _('English')),
      ('es', _('Spanish')),
  ]

(**Note:** This is my case, where I want to translate the store into German, Spanish and English)

After doing that, I run my server and only these three languages appear in the select language box, but when I push the button in order to translate the page, It returns the default language (English) every time, getting this in each translation petition:

```
"POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8379
```

Is there any step I'm skipping or anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a partial (almost complete) solution. Due to languages I want to use are very common, I used Django translation middleware directly, without using the one Oscar provides. So, my solution is to edit `settings.py` by including in `MIDDLEWARE` (or in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASES` depending of Django version) the Django internacionalization middleware: `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`.

After that, **without** importing `ugettext` (`from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`), feel free to add languages as follows:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('es', 'Spanish'),
    ('de', 'German'),
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('pt-br', 'Brazilian'),
    #... and so on
]
```

This solution doesn't need creating symbolic links or additional folders.